# Dynamically update the calculated column value based on other values

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp

I have a calculated field of type currency inside SharePoint named Extension4 with the following formula:-

[image]

now when i added the 3 fields inside power app Extension4,UnitPrice4 (of type currency) & Quantity4 (of type number) >> when i change the UnitPrice4 and/or the Quantity4 >> the Extension4 will not get updated.. can anyone advice how i can make the calculated field dynamic inside power app?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce on my end... Did you apply any formula to those field controls?

Comment: @Allen_MSFT so in your case the calculated columns inside power app will get updated automatically (without submitting the form) when you chnage the related field?